# How to print out values in steps of 10 using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, for-loop, range

this code prints out the values from -30 up to 40, but I need it to print out the values from -30 to 40 in steps of 10.

```
for x in range(-30, 40):
        print(x)
```

Can someone help me? I wasn't able to find anything when googeling this problem.

Comment: The Python documentation has the answer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range.

Answer (score 3):

The third argument for `range` is the `step`, so just use:

```
for x in range(-30, 40, 10):
    print(x)
```

However note that the `stop` is exclusive, so if you wanted to include `40` it should be:

```
for x in range(-30, 41, 10):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Following the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

The documentation *defines* `range` as taking three arguments:

> range(start, stop[, step])

The last argument, `step`, is the interval for each `loop`. So, to `loop` `x` in intervals of `10`, we can set the `step` argument to `10`:

```
for x in range(-30, 40, 10):
   print(x)
```

which `prints` out the following values for `x`:

```
-30
-20
-10
0
10
20
30
```

*N.B. that as `range` stops when it reaches the `stop` argument (exclusive), `40` is not included.*

Answer (score 0):

Since print in python 3+ is a function, you can achieve the same result using:

**Code:**

```
print(*range(-40, 41, 10), sep="\n")
```

**output**

```
-40
-30
-20
-10
0
10
20
30
40
```

Basically print will unpack the range and use separator `\n`.